# Portable null device in R

Tags: r, null, multiplatform

Is there a portable way to get the null device in R?

At the moment I am doing this:

```
dev.null <- ifelse(.Platform$OS.type == "windows", "NUL:", "/dev/null")
```

And later I can for instance `sink(dev.null)` or `try(..., outFile = dev.null)`.

However that doesn't seem very robust to me. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why do you need `sink(dev.null)`?

Comment: @roland I have some output from calls that I need to silence. I realize I could also use try(..., outFile = dev.null) in this case, this seems to be new. I hope there can be a generic way to do it.

Comment: what about `capture.output()` or `suppressMessages()` or `suppressWarnings()`? Not sure if this is an alternative. I mean you need to surround each function call with unwanted output with these commands.

Comment: you could combine `invisible()` with `capture.output(..., file = NULL)`, e.g. `invisible(capture.output(print("hi")))`

Comment: @drmariod @RolandASc sure I could but it's a bit cumbersome to wrap everything like that... Surely there has to be something equivalent to `.Platform$file.sep` and `file.path` to build paths, but for `/dev/null`...

Comment: well if you look on Wikipedia, then this simple switch is maybe not sufficient: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device. However, Henrik Bengtsson had a similar wish expressed here: https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/11. I think what you are doing at the moment is perfectly fine, apart from not differentiating more for Windows types

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This thread is quite old, but was the first I found when googling this topic, so I thought it may be worth mentioning [nullfile](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.10.1/topics/nullfile).

> nullfile() returns a character string, which is "/dev/null" except on Windows where it is "nul:"

As of R version 3.6.0, this function is available in the base namespace. Otherwise, you can find it in the R.utils package

```
sink(nullfile())
print("I am about to be tossed into the void, irrespective of the OS this is run on")
sink()
```